# How to remove XML Tag Blocks from the command line with one or more occurrences

Tags: xml, sed, gpx

I have an xml file that looks something like this:

```
<xml>
  <trkseg>
  <note>
    <to>A</to>
    <from>B</from>
    <body>
      keep this
    </body>
  </trkseg>
  <trkseg>
  </note>
  ...
  </trkseg>
</xml>
```

And I wanted to remove all the following code. This combination of tags can occur more than once in the file:

```
</trkseg>
<trkseg>
```

Any tips on how to fix this?

What I expected was this:

```
<xml>
  <trkseg>
  <note>
    <to>A</to>
    <from>B</from>
    <body>
      keep this
    </body>
  </note>
  ...
  </trkseg>
</xml>
```

I tried using this sed command but doesn't work the way I want:

```
sed -i '' -e '/<\/trkseg>/,/<trkseg>/d' my-file.xml
```

I get this result:

```
<xml>
  <trkseg>
  <note>
    <to>A</to>
    <from>B</from>
    <body>
      keep this
    </body>
  </note>
  ...
```

Comment: The file you've shown isn't XML, because the `note` and `trkseg` elements overlap. That's the problem with using non-XML tools (such as sed) to create or manipulate XML, it's very easy to end up with ill-formed XML which can't be processed.

Comment: My bad. I made a test file. The file I wanted to change with the above command was a gpx file. I will post it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with GNU sed

sample file

```
<xml>
  <trkseg>
    one
    two
  </trkseg>
  <trkseg>
    three
    four
  </trkseg>
</xml>
```

sed script

```bash
sed -znr '{
  :-A s/<[\/]trkseg>/&/2;t-B;b-C
  :-B s/[[:space:]]*<[\/]trkseg>//1;t-A
  :-C s/[[:space:]]*<trkseg>//2g;p
}' file
```

output:

```
<xml>
  <trkseg>
    one
    two
    three
    four
  </trkseg>
</xml>
```

Comment: Wow. That's it . The actual code looks like a foreign language to me but it does the trick. I'm using this code on macOS so I had to install GNU sed. With this command: `brew install gnu-sed`
And I ran it with this command: `gsed -znr '{commandA;commandB;commandC}' original.gpx > new.gpx`
You really helped me a lot my providing this code. This will save me hours of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with an XSLT transformation. In XSLT 3.0 it's:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0">
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:template match="trk">
    <xsl:copy-of select="* except *:trkseg"/>
    <xsl:copy select="*:trkseg[1]">
      <xsl:copy-of select="*:trkseg/*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time again to comment. Really appreciate it.
What I did ws installing Saxon with help of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FsDq2-VV0Uo. I also downloaded the latest Saxon files from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/latest/download.
Unfortunately you transformation code didn't work or I'm probably doing something wrong. I used this command: `java -jar saxon-he-11.3.jar -xsl:transform.xsl -s:trackcombo.gpx -o:myoutputfile.gpx` Both the transform.xsl and the trackcombo.gpx are in the same folder as the jar file.

Comment: Hard to know what's wrong when you haven't given any clues as to how it failed.

Comment: I already found another solution using gnu sed. Thank again for replying.